# How can I change only one item in viewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, notify

I use a viewPager which has images. I want to change only one image to reset the zooming feature like `notifyItemChanged` in viewPager adapter. 
I added `onPageChangeListener` but I can't find do it by using `onPageSelected` or `destroyItem`. How can I do it?

**MyActivity:**

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                    //I CAN'T FIND HOW TO RESET ZOOMING IMAGE AT POSITION
                    displayMetaInfo(position);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                }
            });
```

**MyAdapter :**

```
private class MyViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        TouchImageView photoView;

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.show_images, container, false);

            photoView = ViewUtil.findById(view, R.id.photoView);

            Image image = allImages.get(position);
            if (image != null) {

              String path = image.getPath();

              if (hasPathControl(path)) {
               setImage();
               loadImage(path, photoView);
            }

            container.addView(view);

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return allImages.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object obj) {
            return view == (obj);
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {

            Mylog.i(TAG, " destroyItem position " + position);

            container.removeView((View) object);

        }

        private void loadImage(String path, TouchImageView imageView) {

            glideRequests.load(path)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                    .dontTransform()
                    .override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL)
                    .transition(withCrossFade())
                    .into(imageView);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by change ?

Comment: I want to change only one image to reset the zooming feature

Comment: Yeah what do you mean? You want to add a new image?

Comment: Simply use, switch case for `positon` in `onPageSelected` method. And perform specific task for specific position.

Comment: maybe I should use `destroyItem`

Comment: Are you using any ZoomImageView or anything else,
You can get views by calling getChildAt () and reset it.

Comment: can you share sample code?

Comment: You can check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I override the onPageSelected() and get the views by calling getChildAt() method.

I didn't test the code but hope this will help you.
I have used the TouchImageView before but didn't try this.

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    if (position > 0) {
        View view = mPager.getChildAt(position);
        if (view != null) {
            TouchImageView img = (TouchImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
            img.resetZoom();
        }
    }
}
```